# NoClassDefFoundError for package private scala object in Android project

Tags: android, scala, proguard, noclassdeffounderror, dalvik

I'm trying to use Json4s in an Android project. My project compiles, etc, but I'm seeing the following errors:

> W/dalvikvm(24527): VFY: unable to find class referenced in signature
>   (Lcom/thoughtworks/paranamer/CachingParanamer;) I/dalvikvm(24527):
>   Could not find method
>   com.thoughtworks.paranamer.CachingParanamer.lookupParameterNames,
>   referenced from method
>   org.json4s.Meta$ParanamerReader$.lookupParameterNames
>   W/dalvikvm(24527): VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 11:
>   Lcom/thoughtworks/paranamer/CachingParanamer;.lookupParameterNames
>   (Ljava/lang/reflect/AccessibleObject;)[Ljava/lang/String;
>   D/dalvikvm(24527): VFY: replacing opcode 0x6e at 0x0008
>   E/dalvikvm(24527): Could not find class
>   'com.thoughtworks.paranamer.CachingParanamer', referenced from method
>   org.json4s.Meta$. W/dalvikvm(24527): VFY: unable to resolve
>   new-instance 15 (Lcom/thoughtworks/paranamer/CachingParanamer;) in
>   Lorg/json4s/Meta$; D/dalvikvm(24527): VFY: replacing opcode 0x22 at
>   0x0013 W/dalvikvm(24527): VFY: unable to find class referenced in
>   signature (Lcom/thoughtworks/paranamer/CachingParanamer;)
>   D/dalvikvm(24527): DexOpt: unable to opt direct call 0x0009 at 0x17 in
>   Lorg/json4s/Meta$;. D/dalvikvm(24527): DexOpt: unable to opt
>   direct call 0x000a at 0x1a in Lorg/json4s/Meta$;.
>   W/dalvikvm(24527): Exception Ljava/lang/NoClassDefFoundError; thrown
>   while initializing Lorg/json4s/Meta$; W/System.err(24527):
>   java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError W/System.err(24527):    at
>   org.json4s.Extraction$.mkMapping$1(Extraction.scala:207)
>   W/System.err(24527):  at
>   org.json4s.Extraction$.org$json4s$Extraction$$extract0(Extraction.scala:214)
>   W/System.err(24527):  at
>   org.json4s.Extraction$.extract(Extraction.scala:47)
>   W/System.err(24527):  at
>   org.json4s.ExtractableJsonAstNode.extract(ExtractableJsonAstNode.scala:21)
>   W/System.err(24527):  at
>   models.Metadata$$anon$1.(Metadata.scala:21) W/System.err(24527):
>     at models.Metadata$.fromJson(Metadata.scala:20) W/System.err(24527):
>     at my.last.attempt.MainActivity.doStuff(MainActivity.scala:55)
>   W/System.err(24527):  at
>   my.last.attempt.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.scala:18)
>   W/System.err(24527):  at
>   android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5048)
>   W/System.err(24527):  at
>   android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1094)
>   W/System.err(24527):  at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2052)
>   W/System.err(24527):  at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2113)
>   W/System.err(24527):  at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.access$700(ActivityThread.java:139)
>   W/System.err(24527):  at
>   android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1224)
>   W/System.err(24527):  at
>   android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
>   W/System.err(24527):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
>   W/System.err(24527):  at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4918)
>   W/System.err(24527):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native
>   Method) W/System.err(24527):  at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511) W/System.err(24527):
>     at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1004)
>   W/System.err(24527):  at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:771)
>   W/System.err(24527):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
>   W/System.err(24527): Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:
>   com.thoughtworks.paranamer.CachingParanamer W/System.err(24527):  at
>   org.json4s.Meta$.(Meta.scala:93) W/System.err(24527):   at
>   org.json4s.Meta$.(Meta.scala) W/System.err(24527):    ... 22
>   more I/dalvikvm(24527): Rejecting re-init on previously-failed class
>   Lorg/json4s/Meta$; v=0x0 D/AndroidRuntime(24527): Shutting down VM
>   W/dalvikvm(24527): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception
>   (group=0x40dc0438) E/AndroidRuntime(24527): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>   E/AndroidRuntime(24527): java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:
>   org/json4s/Meta$ E/AndroidRuntime(24527):     at
>   org.json4s.Extraction$.mkMapping$1(Extraction.scala:207)
>   E/AndroidRuntime(24527):  at
>   org.json4s.Extraction$.org$json4s$Extraction$$extract0(Extraction.scala:214)
>   E/AndroidRuntime(24527):  at
>   org.json4s.Extraction$.extract(Extraction.scala:47)
>   E/AndroidRuntime(24527):  at
>   org.json4s.ExtractableJsonAstNode.extract(ExtractableJsonAstNode.scala:21)
>   E/AndroidRuntime(24527):  at
>   my.last.attempt.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.scala:44)
>   E/AndroidRuntime(24527):  at
>   android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5048)
>   E/AndroidRuntime(24527):  at
>   android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1094)
>   E/AndroidRuntime(24527):  at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2052)
>   E/AndroidRuntime(24527):  at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2113)
>   E/AndroidRuntime(24527):  at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.access$700(ActivityThread.java:139)
>   E/AndroidRuntime(24527):  at
>   android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1224)
>   E/AndroidRuntime(24527):  at
>   android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
>   E/AndroidRuntime(24527):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
>   E/AndroidRuntime(24527):  at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4918)
>   E/AndroidRuntime(24527):  at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
>   E/AndroidRuntime(24527):  at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
>   E/AndroidRuntime(24527):  at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1004)
>   E/AndroidRuntime(24527):  at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:771)
>   E/AndroidRuntime(24527):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native
>   Method)

I'm not sure if there's an issue with the dalvikvm specifically or just a proguard issue. If it's relevant, the source for Json4s.Meta looks like this:

```
package org.json4s

import java.lang.reflect.{Constructor => JConstructor, Field, Type, ParameterizedType, GenericArrayType}
import java.util.Date
import java.sql.Timestamp
import com.thoughtworks.paranamer.{ParameterNamesNotFoundException, BytecodeReadingParanamer, CachingParanamer}
import scalashim._

case class TypeInfo(clazz: Class[_], parameterizedType: Option[ParameterizedType])

trait ParameterNameReader {
  def lookupParameterNames(constructor: JConstructor[_]): Traversable[String]
}

private[json4s] object Meta {
  import com.thoughtworks.paranamer._
```

Followed by bunch of case classes, etc.

Any how ideas on how I can resolve this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like the class `com.thoughtworks.paranamer.CachingParanamer` is missing from the code. This could be because it was missing from the libraries to start with, or because ProGuard has removed or renamed it (erroneously?).

In the former case, you should make sure that all the necessary libraries are present in your libs directory. ProGuard should be complaining if any classes seem to be missing from the input.

In the latter case, you should make sure that you are using the latest version of ProGuard (4.8 or 4.9beta at this time) inside the Android SDK. If that doesn't help, you could try to preserve the class explicitly:

```
-keep class com.thoughtworks.paranamer.CachingParanamer
```

It's unlikely to be a proper solution, because ProGuard really should figure this out for you.